# Fast and memory-efficient sorting of a large number of 64-bit integers

Tags: c#, binary-search

**The problem:**

I need to run calculations on some data and see if I already have the result in a large table.  I've been using a bloom filter to check the calculations against, but I've realized that a simple binary search would be much more efficient.  To do this, however, I need to pre-sort the items to check against.  Because the items I need to check against are already hashes (basically uniformly random), I've decided to simply use the last 8 bytes of those hashes as the key to sort by.  There are over 1 billion items to check against, so a binary search would use ~8GB of memory with a false positive (ie collision) rate of 1 in 2^64.  A bloom filter with the same number of items and false positive rate (and using 18 hashes) would take ~25GB+, so the binary search is much more efficient.

Like I said though, there are over 1 billion items to sort.  I've tried using a `SortedSet` in C#, and it works, but it takes hours to add items and 85GB of memory, which is 10x the size of the final binary output file.  The `SortedSet` uses a special `IComparer` that operates on the 8-byte byte arrays instead of converting the last 8 bytes to big-endian `ulong`s.

**The question:**

Is there a more memory-efficient way to sort that many byte arrays/`ulong`s?  It would be great if it were faster too, but I'm most concerned about the memory usage.  I'd like to stick with C# if possible (because dealing with the input files is a lot easier), but I could also go with C.

Comment: Radix sort with 2^16 buckets will sort the list in 8 passes. It has good locality and runs in linear time. Requires auxiliary data equal to the size of the list being sorted

Comment: Why not an array of arrays, and sort that using a custom comparer? Then do `Array.BinarySearch`. A Radix tree might not save that much, because the hashes will differ very quickly so the tree will be deep. Maybe a B+ tree?

Comment: I implemented the radix sort in C, and now instead of using 85GB and 7 hours to sort, it uses 16GB and **1 minute**!  On a laptop!